# Two Factor Authentication in .Net Core - How To Validate Token

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, jwt, .net-core-3.1, two-factor-authentication

I'm implementing two-factor authentication in .Net Core 3.1 for a SPA client. I've already set up the Jwt Authentication so bearer tokens are supposed to be issued upon successful 2fa validation. I'm not sure how the password authentication fits with 2fa. If the password is valid and 2fa is not enabled then .Net Core API can simply return the JWT Bearer token, if 2fa is enabled here is what I'm thinking (I'm not using Identity so UserManager class is not an option):

1. Upon successful password authentication return an expired JWT token(temporary token).
2. User is rerouted to the 2FA screen and inputs 2FA code then submits to API together with the temporary token.
3. In the server validate the temporary token using JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken passing in TokenValidationParameters with a setting of ValidateLifetime = false.
4. Upon validation of the 2fa code and temporary token return the final JWT token to be used as authorization header in subsequent API calls.

Step 1 seems a bit risky for me since the temporary token has no expiration - if an attacker has access to this token then he can brute force the system since 2FA code is only 6 digits. On the other hand, issuing a token with a shorter lifespan, say 2 minutes, seems risky too since the token can now be actually used in other endpoints. What is the general guideline when it comes to 2FA flow?

Comment: Another idea I have is to have a separate token issuer, with a different signing key, for the sole purpose of 2FA code. This time I can issue a token with a shorter lifespan but still cannot be used on other endpoints. Seems like a good idea, but still looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with creating a one-time use token, with a short lifespan. The one-time token uses the user's hashed password and the last login date as the signing key. This makes it one-time as when the user logs in the last login date changes.